# How do I paste a text from the clipboard as if the characters were typed one by one?

Tags: windows, copy-paste, clipboard, confluence

Some rich text editors, e.g. Confluence, allow typing formatted content as markup and convert it to rich-text on the fly. This means I cannot paste markup content into the editor.

How do I simulate typing the copied text from my clipboard content into the rich-text editor?

Comment: [This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/46988) do the thing.

Answer (score 3):

You're after a tool, which is off topic. I'm also not going to do your work, but will provide you the steps you need :)

For your needs you can use `Auto Hot Key`

The logic is you copy text, iterate through and send each character

Pasting from the clipboard should be simple https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/103489-pasting-clipboard-contents/

You then iterate through each character in the clipboard
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm

and finally send that character via `Send`

Comment: A loop in AHK, that's a brilliant idea! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

; once the script is running, you have 3 seconds to switch to the
; position and wait for the insertion of the texts within the clipboard

Sleep 3000 ; wait 3 seconds
Send, %clipboard%
Return

Comment: Take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer